# http://Something instead http://srvsp:18000/sites/Something

Tags: url, site, collection

I just have been assigned to administer SharePoint

My first assignment is to shorten the url of collections

for example guys want to use `http://Sales` instead `http://srvssp:18085/sites/Sales`

Is there any link for articles covering this issue?

Comment: OMG, they built the sites under Central Admin?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can create Host Named Site Collections instead of Path based site collections where you can have the desired name for the site collection.

like http://sales , http://purchase

these host named site collections only can be created through power shell as there is no way to create through UI .

refer this [Host Named Site Collection in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx) for more info on this .

Comment: thank mate,.. will try host named and alternate access mapping

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they created the sites under Central Administration. If so, you should correct that before you do anything else.

I would start by creating a New Web application and Content Database. You can apply the URL as the host header of "Sales", but you need to be sure the DNS points to your farm for that. Then you can move the site collection to the new web application.

Another alternative mentioned above is the option for Host Named Site Collections. It requires that you get the DNS right and a bit more PowerShell, but may serve you better in the end, depending on your plans.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could look at the managed paths

- Open Sharepoint Central Administration -> Application Managment -> Manage web applications
- Select your web application
- Click Managed Paths button on the ribbon

You will see that there are at least two path:

1. Root (Explicit inclusion)
2. sites (Wildcard inclusion)

Explicit inclusion means that you can create only one site collection with this path. Wildcard inclusion means that you can create so many sites as you wish.

if you would not want to use \sites, you can add you own path. After this you can select this path on site collection creation page.

Try this,

**Please make sure you implement a 'root' site collection as this will leave you unsupported if you don't. Without a root site collection many things break, like InfoPath, Workflows, Visio services as these all expect the root site collection to exist.**